# Lagrange's identity: scalar and cross product

Tags: proof-explanation, inner-products, applications, cross-product

Let $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ be vectors in $3-$space. Then $$(\mathbf v\bullet\mathbf w)^2+|\mathbf v\times\mathbf w|^2=|\mathbf v|^2 |\mathbf w|^2, \quad \text{Lagrange's identity}.$$

> Neglecting the proof, I am curious to know the practical meaning of this identity in the exercises and what it is used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a particular case...involved in 3d surface relationships ... in the derivation of geodesic curvature $=kg$ formula in differential geometry. This vector is orthogonal to the curve.

It may be found in text-books of differential geometry, maybe in Weatherburn's.

Practically, vector addition of  components cos ( dot product) and sin ( cross product ) of angles  between the individual vectors should result in their (squared)  scalar product of individual vector norms.

$$ \vec a \times \vec b= a\;b \sin \theta $$
$$ \vec a \cdot  \vec b=  a\;b \cos \theta $$

Eliminate $\theta$

$$|\vec a \cdot \vec b |^2 +| \vec a \times \vec b |^2=a^2 b^2 $$

Among many examples of such Pythagorean resolution is the curvature vector of a small circle on the sphere can be generalized to any surface in $ \mathbb R^3 $

[image: Resolution]

$$k^2=k_g^2+k_n^2$$

*Situations not fully known to me is total energy  $ E$  conserved in dynamics of rotation and translation:*

$$ E^2 = Torque^2+ Work ^2 = |F\times r|^2 +|F \cdot r|^2$$

[Wiki for Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity)

Comment: I appreciated your answer and your interesting for my question. +1....Your link it is a "poem". My problem it is to understand the whole link :(

Comment: I am unable to recall now, it comes in a critical place in a derivation. Will give it when I find it.

Comment: Surely my eyes are closed for sleep and yawns are many.... but I have little understood it. :-(

Comment: Yes, it comes in the derivation of *geodesic curvature* $=k_g$ formula in differential geometry. This vector is orthogonal to the curve.

Comment: I accept your answer but I did not understand anything . Maybe a drawing or a your personal mathematical explanation answer could help me. I have never studied differential geometry and I thank you so much for your kind answer that I accept it gladly. Thank you very much.