# How to simplify dot product of cross product by itself $(a \times b) \cdot (a \times b)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $a$ and $b$ are vectors in $R3$. Is it possible to simplify this? I could try to simplify it myself but if the simplification result is already widely known I wanted to ask it here.

Comment: It is $(a\times b)^2$. Do you mean $\Bbb R^3$ together with the cross product?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes sorry that's right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lagrange's identity: scalar and cross product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3862380/lagranges-identity-scalar-and-cross-product)

Comment: @DietrichBurde No I don't see how it does.

Comment: Well, you just accepted it below, so I guess you see how to use Lagrange identity. That's what the duplicate does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$(a \times b) \cdot (a \times b)= ||a \times b||^2= ||a||^2 \cdot ||b||^2-(a \cdot b)^2.$$

Lagrange's identity.

Comment: Thank you! Could this also be expressed as $(a \cdot a )(b \cdot b) - (a \cdot b)^2$?

Comment: But is that a simplification? E.g., computationally, we need 6 multiplications to form $a\times b$, then 3 multiplications for squareing it. On the right hand side, we naively have 3 multiplications to form $a^2$, 3 more for $b^2$, 3 more for $ab$, and then still 2 more multiplications ...